# to get a string value of firstactivity and second activity to third activity and i to get the listview in dialogue in onPost execute

Tags: android, database, android-intent

I have 3 activities. I'm trying to get a string value from the first Activity to the second Activity. And then I want both the string value of the first Activity and the second Activity in the third activity.

How should the code look in my activities to achieve this?

My flow is first I execute the first Activity, then in the first I start the second Activity, and finally in the second I start the third Activity.

I'm getting null as a string value, without any errors in log cat.

I cant able to see the listview in dialogue in Topic.java in onPost Execute but if i use arrayadapter without i can able get the data..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are not sending `SuperSecretValue` and `SuperSecretValue1` from Second Activity to Third Activity Change your Second Activity intent as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Topic.this, QuestionActivity.class);
 String superSecretValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("SuperSecretValue");
 String superSecretValue1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("SuperSecretValue1");

 intent.putExtra("AnotherSuperSecretValue", topicid);
 intent.putExtra("SuperSecretValue", superSecretValue);
 intent.putExtra("SuperSecretValue1", superSecretValue1);
 startActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT :**

if you are starting `QuestionActivity` Activity on Button click then use `Topic.this.getIntent().getStringExtra("SuperSecretValue"); ....`  for getting Intent from previous Activity or second way move your `getIntent` code in `onCreate` method after `setContentView`  of Activity

Comment: In first activity the name SuperSecretValue is what we keeps only

Comment: Im starting second Activity on listview click and third activity also on list view click. In third activity i wrote the intent in oncreate

Comment: @OneManArmy : try after getting all values in onCreate of Topic Activity

Comment: If i get all values in onCreate of TopicActivity how should start third activity..and i should run topic activity also

Comment: @OneManArmy : declare `superSecretValue,superSecretValue1,..`  as `public static` at class level before `onCreate` and again value inside onCreate from getIntent . then just use `intent.putExtra("SuperSecretValue", superSecretValue);...` on listview click to start Activity

Comment: @OneManArmy :in Topic Activity  you will need to declare

Comment: sorry i didnt get any data..i post my full code of three activity..lets check it..

Comment: How to paste in that pastebin.com bro

Comment: @OneManArmy : just copy paste your code in given area and click sumbit button in buttom

Comment: It showing error telling Remove final modifier in superSecretValue

Comment: @OneManArmy : yes remove final from both strings

Comment: sorry bro i didnt get the data in print sts.. there is no error also... i think in my third activity php file error. the data didnt get from database..but these data are getting from first and second activity only. there the php file is correct..help me bro what is the solution for this..

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/14869783/problems-in-radiobuttons see the link and answer it please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put value in second activity when you start the third activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Topic.this, QuestionActivity.class);
String superSecretValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("SuperSecretValue");
String superSecretValue1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("SuperSecretValue1");
intent.putExtra("SuperSecretValue",superSecretValue );// here is missing
intent.putExtra("SuperSecretValue1",superSecretValue1 ); // here is missing
intent.putExtra("AnotherSuperSecretValue", topicid);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: See my above code and my explain...tell what is the solution for this? what i should change? help me thanks a lot in advance

Comment: i Want add this line    'params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));'    now i got the value

Answer (score 1):

```
In second activity try this

Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();

String superSecretValue = bundle.getString("SuperSecretValue");   
String superSecretValue1 =bundle.getString("SuperSecretValue1");

Intent intent = new Intent(Topic.this, QuestionActivity.class);  
intent.putExtra("AnotherSuperSecretValue", topicid);
intent.putExtra("SuperSecretValue",superSecretValue );
intent.putExtra("SuperSecretValue1",superSecretValue1 );  
startActivity(intent);

Again, in third activity, try this

Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();  
String topicValue = bundle.getString("AnotherSuperSecretValue");  
String levelValue = bundle.getString("SuperSecretValue");  
String groupValue1 = bundle.getString("SuperSecretValue1");

System.out.println("Result:"+topicValue);  
System.out.println("Result:"+levelValue);  
System.out.println("Result:"+groupValue1);
```

Comment: i Want add this line in doInBackground   'params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));'    now i got the value